# Web Page Complexity Limits - If there are any

Tags: complexity-theory, limit, html

i was wondering i am having

- jQuery
- Javascript
- Javascript Timers
- CSS
- DIVs    inside DIVs
- Tables inside Tables
- Table   inside DIVs
- DIVs     inside Tables

and all possible combination of all of the above in one webpage and my website is consisted of such many pages and worst all these pages are generated with PHP...

i was wondering is there some point where its like **OKAY THATS ENOUGH FOR BROWSER, NO MORE** complexity...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Facebook news-feed page (with 'Older posts' clicked a few times) contains nearly 20,000 tags, and still scrolls smoothly. You're going to have a bloated and slow-loading page far before the user's browser gives in.

Comment: well, facebook's text & html colors based simple design might be contributing a lot to it.. but 20,000.. RESPECT...

Answer (score 0):

I think a browser has no complexity limit, except the memory, disk space limit the computer itself has.
Are you doing an experiment or actually making a practical site with full of elements?

Comment: well i have not yet gone too complex but wanted to know my limitations if there are none then may be i should go ahead and give it my worst shot but i bet its gonna look great.....